# pyspark read csv with user specified schema - returned all StringType

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

New to pyspark. I am trying to read the csv file from datalake blob using pyspark with user-specified schema structure type. Below is the code I tried.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

customschema = StructType([
StructField("A", StringType(), True)
,StructField("B", DoubleType(), True)
,StructField("C", TimestampType(), True)
])

df_1 = spark.read.format("csv").options(header="true", schema=customschema, multiline="true", enforceSchema='true').load(destinationPath)

df_1.show()
```

Out:

```
+---------+------+--------------------+
|        A|     B|                   C|
+---------+------+--------------------+
|322849691|9547.0|2020-09-24 07:30:...|
|322847371| 492.0|2020-09-23 13:15:...|
|322329853|6661.0|2020-09-07 09:45:...|
|322283810| 500.0|2020-09-04 13:12:...|
|322319107| 251.0|2020-09-02 13:51:...|
|322319096| 254.0|2020-09-02 13:51:...|
+---------+------+--------------------+
```

But I got the field type as String instead. I am not quite sure what I have done wrong.

```
df_1.printSchema()
```

Out:

```
root
 |-- A: string (nullable = true)
 |-- B: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use DataFrameReader `load` method you should pass the schema using `schema` and not in the options :

```
df_1 = spark.read.format("csv") \
    .options(header="true", multiline="true")\
    .schema(customschema).load(destinationPath)
```

That's not the same as the API method `spark.read.csv` which accepts `schema` as an argument :

```
df_1 = spark.read.csv(destinationPath, schema=customschema, header=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

It works with the following syntax

```
customschema=StructType([
    StructField("A",StringType(), True),
    StructField("B",DoubleType(), True),
    StructField("C",TimestampType(), True)
])

df = spark.read.csv("test.csv", header=True, sep=";", schema=customschema)

df.show()
df.printSchema()
```

or you can also use

```
df = spark.read.load("test.csv",format="csv", sep=";", schema=customschema, header="true")
```

It is interesting that the read().option().load() syntax does not work for me either. I am not sure if it works at all. At least according to the documentation .options() is only used for write(), so to export a dataframe.

Another option would be to cast the datatypes afterwards

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df=(df
      .withColumn("B",f.col("B").cast("string"))
      .withColumn("B",f.col("B").cast("double"))
      .withColumn("C",f.col("C").cast("timestamp"))
     )
```

Comment: i tried using spark.read.csv, it works too. thanks Alex.