# How to prevent SQL Server from stripping leading zeros when importing data

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2019

A `data file` is imported to a `SQL Server` table. One of the columns in data file is of text data type with values in this column to be integers only. The corresponding column in destination table in SQL Server db is of type `varchar(100)`. But after data import, SQL Server is storing the values such as `0474525431` as `4.74525431E8` that is a `Scientific Notations`.

**Question**: In the above situation how can we prevent SQL server from storing the values into `Scientific Notations`. For example when `0474525431` is inserted into a `VARCHAR(100)` column it should be stored as is and not as `4.74525431E8`

**UPDATE**:

The code to import data:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df = spark.read.csv(".../Test/MyFile.csv", header="true", inferSchema="true")

server_name = "jdbc:sqlserver://{SERVER_ADDR}"
database_name = "database_name"
url = server_name + ";" + "databaseName=" + database_name + ";"

table_name = "table_name"
username = "username"
password = "myPassword"

try:
  df.write \
    .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .option("url", url) \
    .option("dbtable", table_name) \
    .option("user", username) \
    .option("password", password) \
    .save()
except ValueError as error :
    print("Connector write failed", error)
```

**UPDATE2**:

The issue seems to be related to the leading zeros, as well. I created a sample file (shown below) and imported its data to corresponding SQL table (also shown below) and noticed that the leading zeros were removed. This is happening despite the fact that all 6 columns in data file and the table are text (varchar):

Data file:

```
Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4|Col5|Col6
abc|12345|Y|0123456789|D|Test
xyz|54321|Y|0123456789|D|Test
rst|67891|Y|0123456789|D|Test
uvw|65432|Y|0123456789|D|Test
```

**Table after data import**:
[image]

Comment: How are you importing the data? It *sounds* like it's being treated as a `float`, are you using ODBC / OLEDB?

Comment: @Stu The data is imported into `Azure SQL Db` using `JDBC`.

Comment: A possible workaround is to cast the value to a bigint before casting / inserting to varchar

Comment: You'll need to post the Java/JDBC code.  SQL Server wouldn't do that by itself.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Good point. Let me add what you suggested.

Comment: What does the problematic value itself looks like?

Comment: @SalmanA One such value is specified in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark is inferring the schema, and it's picking `integer` for the column containing the value '0474525431'.  So as the DataFrame is read the value is convered to an integer and the leading zero is discarded.

So you need to make sure the DataFrame has the correct types. You can either specify the schema explicitly when you create the DataFrame, or turn off `inferSchema` and then convert selected columns to different types before loading to SQL Server. Examples of both are in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66131959/pyspark-read-csv-with-user-specified-schema-returned-all-stringtype).

Here's a sample showing that the leading '0' is preserved if the DataFrame uses a `string` column rather than an `integer` column.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

jdbcUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://{0}:{1};database={2}".format(jdbcHostname, jdbcPort, jdbcDatabase)
connectionProperties = {
  "user" : jdbcUsername,
  "password" : jdbcPassword,
  "driver" : "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
}

pushdown_query = "(select '0474525431' f, * from sys.objects) emp"
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=pushdown_query, properties=connectionProperties)

df.write.mode("overwrite").option("header",True).csv("datalake/temp.csv")

df = spark.read.csv("datalake/temp.csv", header="true", inferSchema="false")
df.printSchema()


table_name = "table_name"

try:
  df.write \
    .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
    .option("dbtable", table_name) \
    .option("user", jdbcUsername) \
    .option("password", jdbcPassword) \
    .save()
except ValueError as error :
    print("Connector write failed", error)

df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=table_name, properties=connectionProperties)
display(df)
```

Comment: Browne-Microsoft David, I've used `df.printSchema()` to verify that the column in question is of type string - and that the other data types match the data types in destination table that is created ahead of time. The data is imported successfully in all columns. But this columns is storing data in Scientific Notations probably just because of the values in this column are long integers such as `0474525431`

Comment: @DavidBrowneMicrosoft Your suggestion worked. Thank you for sharing your knowledge (and hence helping others). Specifically I liked how you explained what is a reason behind the error.